# 配列のポインタから要素数を出したい

Tags: c

以下の様に引数としてchar型配列の先頭を指すポインタが入ってきた場合、string_ptrを用いてchar型配列の要素数を知りたいです。

```
void hoge(char* string_ptr) {
   
    //char string[100]の場合
    //sizeof(string)/sizeof(char)で割り出せる
}
```

Answer (score 5):

不可能です（だからバッファオーバーラン脆弱性がいまだに発生し続けている）

別途引数を設けるのが普通 `void hoge(char* string_ptr, ssize_t bufsize);`
`hoge()` 側で動的にメモリをとるのが次善

```
char* hoge() {
    char* p=NULL;
    for (ループ条件) {
        char* q=realloc(p, newsize);
        if (q==NULL) { エラー処理して脱出; }
        // エラーが起きていない場合に限り継続
        p=q;
        何らかの処理を p に対して行う;
    }
    return p; // free() するのは呼んだ側の責務
}
```

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 化して `str::string` や `std::vector` や `std::array` を使うのもよし
[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ならこんなイディオムもあり

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void hoge(T (&array)[N]) { ... }
```

# 組み込み系だと c++11 にすら対応してないのでこうするしかない

Answer (score 1):

配列であるなら、おっしゃるように要素数は算出できますが、
ポインタではそれは不可能です

Answer (score -2):

#### 回答

> 配列のポインタから要素数を出したい

以下のように、仮引数の宣言を型と要素数を指定したポインタにすれば可能です。

```
void hoge(char (*string_ptr)[100])
{
    printf("sizeof(*string_ptr)/sizeof(char)=%lu\n", sizeof(*string_ptr)/sizeof(char));
}
```

以下のように、引数を配列形式で宣言する方法はNGです。

```
void hoge(char string[100])
{
    printf("sizeof(string)/sizeof(char)=%lu\n", sizeof(string)/sizeof(char));
}
```

配列形式の仮引数`char string[100]`は`char *`とみなされるようです。
実行した結果も期待した結果になりません。`sizeof(string)`がポインタ変数のサイズになるからです。

なおコンパイルすると以下のような警告が出ます。

```
warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'char *' instead of 'char[100]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
```

---

#### 配列のポインタについて

##### 参考情報

書籍　K&Rのプログラミング言語Ｃ(isbn:9784320021457)　P114
同じくK&Rのプログラミング言語C〔第2版〕(isbn:9784320026926)　P137
に例が載っていました。

##### コンパイラ

動作確認に使用したコンパイラは以下です。

- gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
- Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.2.6

##### 動作確認用コードと実行結果

動作確認に使用したコードは以下です。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void hoge(char (*string_ptr)[100]);
void hoge2(char string[100]);
int main()
{
    char string[100];
    printf("sizeof(string)/sizeof(char)=%lu\n", sizeof(string)/sizeof(char));
    hoge(&string);
    hoge2(string);
    return 0;
}
void hoge(char (*string_ptr)[100])
{
    printf("sizeof(*string_ptr)/sizeof(char)=%lu\n", sizeof(*string_ptr)/sizeof(char));
}
void hoge2(char string[100])
{
    printf("sizeof(string)/sizeof(char)=%lu\n", sizeof(string)/sizeof(char));
}
```

実行結果は以下です。

> sizeof(string)/sizeof(char)=100
> sizeof(*string_ptr)/sizeof(char)=100
> sizeof(string)/sizeof(char)=8